# jockey-gtk on startup

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

When I start a new session on Ubuntu 9.4 I need to run jockey-gtk to enable my wireless networking card:

```
jockey-gtk -e firmware:b43
```

jockey fails if I try to run it from rc.local, even if I try to set DISPLAY first. Is there some way to run this command automatically on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*jockey-gtk* does not work outside of an X environment. This was recently fixed with the addition of *jockey-text*, a command-line text frontend. Check if you can get the package for Karmic containing this fix to work for you. Launchpad bug report with fuller details: [Command-line interface doesn't work without X](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/394688)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then run `apt-get install jockey-gtk` to get the version with jockey-text. After I did that, adding  the line `jockey-text -e firmware:b43` in \etc\rc.local successfully enabled my wireless card when my session started. 
Then I removed that line, or else apt-get update will install karmic.